# UITabBar without labels (like Tweetie 2/Twitter for iPhone)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'd like to build an app with a tabbar in the style of Tweetie 2/Twitter for iPhone (that is, images with no labels). I can't see a way to do it with normal UITabBarController/UITabBar, and my current thinking is that it's actually a UIToolbar with a custom view controller that is pushing and popping views from an array to simulate the UITabBarController's default behavior.

Is this the approach that you all would recommend, or is there something more elegant that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarItem/initWithTitle:image:tag:) is how:

```
-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title image:(UIImage *)image tag:(NSInteger)tag
```

Init with a `nil` title, and there will be no text showing.

If you're using IB, you can also just empty the `Title` field.

Comment: *slaps forehead* always nice to start the week feeling like an idiot. :D Thanks!

Comment: However, the title label is still there and makes it impossible to vertically center bigger images.

Comment: @pre then how to remove title label to center icons?